# How to prevent pull to refresh on Safari when keyboard is open?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari, pull-to-refresh

There is css property that prevents pull-to-refresh:

```
overscroll-behavior: none;
```

But it doesnt work when virtual keyboard is open - still posible to scroll down and refresh page. Is there any workaround for such behavior?